# Shaded with "continue on next page"

Tags: page-breaking, framed

I am using the `shaded` environment in the `framed` package to wrap some text lines that may go across two different pages. If there is a crossing of pages, I'd like to automatically add a line "(continue on next page)" to the first shaded box. Is there an easy way to do so? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend to use the newer `mdframed` package instead of the `framed` package. However, it also doesn't seem to have such a feature, but it might be done by patching `\md@putbox@first` and `\md@putbox@middle`.

Comment: I have a new version of `mdframed` Maybe in two weeks the new version will be finished. A current pretest you can download here: http://www.mrunix.de/forums/attachment.php?s=b444c1ab9ba17fd771b5ce3f269ece01&attachmentid=4638&d=1309000477

Comment: I think the usual wording is "continued on next page" as in "This article is continued on the next page", not "continue on next page" as in "Continue reading this article on the next page" (Google: 10m vs. 275k).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use the newer `mdframed` package instead of the `framed` package. However, it also doesn't seem to have such a feature, but it might be done by patching `\md@putbox@first` and `\md@putbox@middle`.

Here something quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@md@putbox@first\md@putbox@first
\def\md@putbox@first{%
    \orig@md@putbox@first
    \nopagebreak
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \vbox to 0pt{\hbox to \linewidth{\hss(continue on next page)}\vss}%
}
\let\orig@md@putbox@middle\md@putbox@middle
\def\md@putbox@middle{%
    \orig@md@putbox@middle
    \nopagebreak
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \vbox to 0pt{\hbox to \linewidth{\hss(continue on next page)}\vss}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray]
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: not tested: `addto\md@putboxfirst{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to \linewidth{\hss(continue on next page)}\vss}}`

Comment: @Macro: That was my very first try as well :-) It didn't work. It places that line on a page of its own afterwards.

Comment: Thanks: Only at the weekend I can spend my time at home. Maybe for the next version it is an inspiration.