# Continuation messages when dialogue breaks across pages

Tags: page-breaking, dramatist

In  it possible to have continuation messages when dialogue breaks across pages? I am trying to replicate automatically the pagebreak style used by *Hansard* (the official record of Parliamentary debates).  My instinct is to try to use the `dramatist` package, but as far as I can tell it does not provide this function.  I would ideally like to find a macro that will insert *[$Charactername]* whenever the environment `\$Characternamespeaks` breaks over a page, as seen in the pictures below.

[image: first part]

[image: second part]

Comment: Please, share a minimal working example.

Comment: `continue` package might help.

Comment: A more manual method: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31710/insert-text-before-end-of-page-and-at-the-beginning-of-the-next-page combines use of `\afterpage` with pagestyle commands.