# "Continued on next page" automatically inserted in footnote

Tags: footnotes, footmisc, bigfoot

Re: *bigfoot* (three different sets of footnotes used) and *footmisc.*

I am looking for a way to have a symbol (~☞) or text (Cont'd.) inserted automatically at the end of each footnote that continues onto the next page, similar to what is possible for tables or [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24106/shaded-with-continue-on-next-page)

(Adding a MWE seems rather pointless.)

PS: As this is NOT a coding problem I'll provide an explanatory screenshot.
[image]

Comment: No! A MWE will serve people as a launch pad and helps them to save some typing. Please provide one.

Comment: MWE is usually the first step to solve the task successfully.