# Automatic insertion of (Cont'd) when footnote splits across pages

Tags: footnotes

Occasionally, I write long footnotes that get split across consecutive pages. Is there a way of automatically inserting *[continues on next page]* and *[continued from previous page]* when such splits happen?

This same question [was already asked some time age](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173930/continued-on-next-page-automatically-inserted-in-footnote), but people refused to provide an answer on the grounds that the OP didn't provide a MWE. So here is mine: a short paragraph with a long footnote.

```
\noindent Both \citet{nykiel-sag11} and \citet{barros14} take this kind of data as 
evidence for generalization (\ref{ex:case-matching-20}) below. We will see in section 
\ref{sec:cleft-sluic} below that this morphological case identity requirement also blocks 
a cleft source for certain sluices. As a consequence, while this requirement is compatible 
with the presence of a regular syntax in the sluicing site, it doesn't provide direct 
evidence in its favor (contrary to \citeauthor{ross69}'s and \citeauthor{merchant99}'s
claims).\footnote{\citeauthor{barros14} treats (\ref{ex:case-matching-20}) as a 
descriptive generalization in need of a more principled explanation. 
\citeauthor{nykiel-sag11}  make the stronger claim that (\ref{ex:case-matching-20}) 
constitutes an argument against the presence of an articulate syntax in the sluicing site. 
Specifically, they claim that, if (\ref{ex:case-matching-20}) is viewed as an overarching 
form requirement on sluicing remnants, it becomes superfluous (and therefore unnecessary) 
to postulate a silent syntax to derive the observed case of the remnant. This line of 
attack is arguably too strong, in that it fails to cover a number of environments where 
case identity doesn't hold. Section \ref{sec:copul-sluic-island} below illustrates this 
effect in the context of LBE sluices in languages with adjectival inflection. Similarly, 
\citet{ince12} points out that, while the subjects of Turkish embedded clauses are 
invariably genitive, remnants of sluicing in the same position are assigned nominative.

\begin{exe}
  \exi{(i)}{\gll Ahmet [\{ $*$ biri-$\varnothing$ / $\checkmark$ biri-nin \} Ankara-ya {git-ti\v g-i}]-ni s\"oyle-di, ama [\{ $\checkmark$ kim-$\varnothing$ / $*$ kim-nin \} \gap] bil-mi-yor-um.\\
   Ahmet {} {} one-{\sc nom} {} {} one-{\sc gen} {} Ankara-{\sc dat} go-{\sc comp -poss.3sg-acc} tell-{\sc pst.3sg} but {} {} who-{\sc nom} {} {} who-{\sc gen} {} {} know-{\sc neg-pres-1sg}\\
  ``Ahmet said that someone went to Ankara, but I don't know who''}
\end{exe}

\noindent Japanese is sometimes reported to exhibit case mismatches too. For example, 
\citet{kizu97} and \citet{merchant98} claim that remnants cannot be case marked (ii), 
although other authors (e.g., \citealt{fukaya12,nakamura12}) provide comparable examples 
where the presence of the case marker is not claimed to induce ungrammaticality 
(this seems to be a point of idiolectal variation; see \citealt{inoue76} and 
\citealt{iseda07}). Similarly, \citet{gribanova13} provides Uzbek examples where a 
case-marked correlate licenses a bare remnant (iii).

\begin{exe}
  \exi{(ii)}{\gll Dareka-ga sono hon-o yon-da ga, watashi-wa [dare($*$-ga) {\gap} ka] wakaranai.\\
  someone-{\sc nom} this book-{\sc acc} read-{\sc pst} but I-{\sc top} {{ }who-{\sc nom}} {} Q know.not\\
  ``Someone read this book, but I don't know who''}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
  \exi{(iii)}{\gll Siz kim-ga-dir pul ber-di-ngiz, lekin [kim(-ga) {\gap} lig-i-ni ] bil-ma-y-man.\\
  you some-{\sc dat}-one money give-{\sc pst-2sg} but {{ }who-{\sc dat}} {} {\sc comp-3sg.poss-acc} {} know-{\sc neg-prs-1sg}\\
  ``You gave money to someone, but I don't know who''}
\end{exe}

\noindent Note that, in all of these classes of examples, the remnant is not overtly 
case marked (depending on one's base assumptions, one could say either that it bears a 
phonetically null case marker or that it is not case marked at all). As far as I know, 
there are no exceptions to (\ref{ex:case-matching-20}) where the remnant bears a 
different overt case marker from the one the correlate does, or where the remnant is 
overtly case-marked and the correlate is bare. At present, I do not know if this is 
a relevant fact or an artifact of the sample I am working with.}

\begin{exe}
  \ex\label{ex:case-matching-20}\emph{Case matching under sluicing}\\*
  In sluicing, given a correlate $C$ and a remnant $R$, if $C$ is a case-bearing category, 
  $R$ and $C$ must have the same case morphology.
\end{exe}
```

Screenshots of compiled .pdf showing footnote split across pages 12 and 13 but without *[continues]* ... *[continued]* markers

[image: page 12]

[image: page 13]

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but you have **not** provided a MWE. A MWE ("Minimal Working Example") is a self-contained document which can actually be compiled using a standard TeX distribution. At the very least your code snippet is lacking the header: It is not a "working" example. Check out [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) question on how to write a proper MWE.

Comment: How would it help your reader to add "Continued on next page" when long footnotes always do continue on the next page? Also, if a footnote is this long and complicated, with its own lists and citations, perhaps it would be better to place it in an appendix.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, but is too long to fit, so...

"How would it help your reader..." E.g. when one uses two or more types of footnotes (with something like the following in the header):

```
\usepackage{alphalph} 
\usepackage{bigfoot}
    \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % footnote author1
    \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{P}[alph] % footnotes author2 in main section
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{K}[arabic] % footnotes author3 in one section
    \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{L}[roman] % footnotes author2 in appendix only
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteP}{%   
  \alphalph{\value{footnoteP}}}  
%\usepackage{perpage}
%   \MakePerPage{footnoteP}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
```

If one then has a long "default" fn plus three or four ones of type P, very often the first fn will flow to page 2, sensibly breaking with no indication that it continues.

(As mentioned just one possible useful application.) If I remember correctly there is a function in OpenOffice that lets one define a "continue" character. (But that's of course off topic.)

Comment: I believe this should be a comment, not an answer.  If it does not provide an answer to the question, but does make a comment, please delete it as a question and re-post it as a comment if you wish to do so.