# How can I break big footnotes using an automatic continued sign?

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking

I have a very big footnote in my latex document. The processor automatically breaks it into two or three pages without any specific sign to show the reader that the text is continued on the next page.

Is there any way to add such sign automatically?

> **This is similar to what I am expecting:**
>
> *First page's footnote:*
>
> <sup>1</sup> long footnote does not finish on the first page
>   →
>
> *Next page's footnote:*
>
> → long footnote continues on the second page.

Comment: To what end? Where else would the footnote be continued? And why haven't you provided a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl))?

Comment: @jon Imagine the page break appears at a full stop. The reader than easily misses that the footnote continues on the next page. Or, when seeing the continuation of the footnote, he is easily confused about what the heck it is.

Comment: @jon I really did not know how to provide a MWE with long texts... sorry if my question does not have one. I want the footnote to continue in the next page with a continued sign and a different footnote separator line, probably a longer line...

Comment: @yo' -- My field involves literature where long footnotes are very common, and it often happens that the a footnote spills over to the next page. 50% of the time, it happens from verso-to-recto ('left page' to 'right page'), in which case there is no confusion. The other 50% of the time it doesn't; and a small fraction of those ends with a full stop where you might think the footnote has finished when it has not. However, upon turning the page, I have never been confused as to what happened. As a TeX puzzle, I'm happy to see an answer; but as a real problem, I just don't see it.

Comment: An MWE is as long as it needs to be. As it turns out your question has been asked at least twice before, but the OP did not provide an MWE in each case, and no one deigned to answer it. You may be more successful if you provide one....

Comment: @jon - Just out of idle curiosity: What *is* your field?

Comment: @Mico -- I work(ed) in medieval legal and political thought, though right now I'm back in school for a (modern) law degree. I still consider the pre-modern stuff my 'true' field, even though I have little time to do real research or writing these days. (Both fields are ones where few people much care about TeX..!)

Comment: @jon - Thanks. Sounds like a rewarding (though maybe also not exactly highly remunerated...) field!

Comment: @Mico -- Haha, very true. There are of course exceptions to the rule (not me), but most people do it for the love. Which is similar to why I stick with (La)TeX even though 95+% of what I publish must be converted to MS Word before submission to a publisher.

Comment: @jon - Doing something out of love for what you're doing is by far the best approach -- in any field. :-)

Comment: @Mico -- Absolutely!! (Of course easier to say that when you're not fixing footnote number 175 of an article people want you to submit in Word.)

Comment: For reference, this question has been asked before: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173930/8528) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194087/8528).

Answer (score 2):

One way to proceed is to load the `footmisc` package with the option `splitrule`. To quote the package's user guide:

> This option ... puts a full-width rule above the split-off part of a split footnote.

On pages without a split-off part of a split footnote, a standard-length footnote rule will be used; however, no continuation sign will be inserted. As @jon has noted in a comment, the likelihood that any confusion may arise because of the absence of a continuation sign must be exceedingly low.

I believe this method -- full-width footnote rule above the split-off part of a split footnote -- pretty much implements standard typographic practice.

Comment: Isn't there anyway to put a continued sign? something like a horizontal arrow at the end of the earlier page's footnote?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - I'm afraid I'm not aware of a ready-made option that would add something like a horizontal arrow at the end of the first (pre-split) part of the footnote.

Comment: I edited my question, example provides more information on what I am thinking about.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - Thanks for providing some additional information. I suspect that what you're looking to achieve may well require some heavy-duty, very-low-level modifications of TeX's algorithms for typesetting footnotes. I'm afraid I do not have this kind of expertise. :-( For sure, the `splitrule` option of the `footmisc` package pursues a much more limited objective.

Comment: So, I can be hopeful if my question lead to an update to LaTeX in its future revisions or cause to born a new package for such purpose. :))